# How can I reference a dictionary in other scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So,
I created a class with what I wanted for items on my inventory

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Also created a dictionary to store the items I would create

```
public Dictionary<string, Item> itemsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
```

I then created an item called "Emspada"

```
public Item Emspada = new Item //atributos do item
{
    ID = 1,
    name = "Emspada"
};
```

Lastly, added the item I created to the dictionary (on void start)

```
dicionarioItems.Add(Emspada.name, Emspada);
```

**But I can't get any value/key from the dictionary**

I don't know how to reference the Key, like

```
itemsDictionary[Emspada.name]
```

Because theres no `Emspada` in current context. How do I get the Key/string value so I can get the actual item Value?
Also: In other scripts how can I get the whole dictionary? Like:

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CreateObj : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject gameObject;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gameObject.name = itemsDictionary["Emspada"];
        //This shows "itemsDictionary does not exit in current context"
        // How do I reference it?
    }
}
```

Comment: "just show theres no Emspada in current context" - That's usually an accurate error message. I recommend learning about variable and method scopes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Comment: We need more context. Where and how are you creating the dictionary? How are you sure you're using the same instance? What does your debugger say about the `.Keys` member of the dictionary object?

Comment: John: like posted, dictionary already on public, dont get why this is happening

Comment: "Dictionary already on public". Nobody is disagreeing with that. "No **Emspada** in current context". Until you post an [mcve] all we can do is assume what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Casing matters, it should be `dicionarioItems["Emspada"]`

Comment: Dai: the class Item is solo on a script. Item creation and Dictionary creation on another script, on the beggining, monobehaviour. on this same script, on the void start, is the dictionary.Add

Comment: @Ron Yes, but the error message OP is getting suggests that there is no `Emspada` object at all in an accessible scope.

Comment: Ron: Yeah, someone just said that, I tried changing, stilll the same error

Comment: @john, I fixed that, the item doesn't exist so the op should use the text key.

Comment: OP: Please provide an [mcve]. This is the only way we can help you.

Comment: Ok, Ill post the full scripts here.

Comment: One fix would be to make it static so change `public Dictionary<string, Item> dicionarioItems` to `public static Dictionary<string, Item> dicionarioItems` and then you can access it like `ListaDeItems.dicionarioItems`. But then each object of `ListaDeItems` will not have its own dictionary.

Comment: @john question edited

Comment: Going back to my original point, you need to learn about scopes. `dicionarioItemsSprites` is an instance variable in the scope created by the class `ListaDeItems`. It is inaccessible outisde `ListaDelItems`. You either need to pass an instance of `ListaDelItems` to `CriarObj` or you need to make `ListaDelItems`'s dictionaries static and then access them like so: `ListaDelItems.dicionarioItems `.

Comment: Ok @john, Newbie programmer here.. thank you so much. With an instance, could I copy all the data from some item on dictionary? My final objective is that these items can get upgrades in-game so I would need them to be 'unique', upgrading 1 `Emspada` wouldnt upgrade them all, if you get what Im saying.

Comment: @Milena If you create an instance in variable a, and assign `b = a`, then b will have access to the _same instance_ as a. If you want unique items, you have to create new ones. You could create a `Copy()` method on item, for example, which would return a new one.

Comment: You need to understand [scope](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1609145&seqNum=4).

Answer (score 0):

you need to look it up by the key

```
Item myitem = dicionarioItems["enter name here"];
```

Comment: does not exit in current context. Tried getting the value using the script the dictionary is in and another.

Comment: Also, A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `ListaDeItems.dicionarioItems'

Comment: @Milena : *`One fix would be to make it static so change public Dictionary<string, Item> dicionarioItems to public static Dictionary<string, Item> dicionarioItems and then you can access it like ListaDeItems.dicionarioItems. But then each object of ListaDeItems will not have its own dictionary.`* – CodingYoshi 1 hour ago